# rsync bash script duplicating dir structure?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-s3

I have a script attaching an Amazon S3 bucket as a mount point on my CentOS 6.5 machine

I am attempting to utilize rsync to copy files from 2 locations to the bucket

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# SET THE BUCKET NAME HERE
S3_BUCKET="my-bucketname";

# SET THE MOUNT POINT HERE
MNT_POINT="/mnt/my-mountpoint";

# Create the mount point if it does not already exist, and set permissions on it
if [[ ! -e $MNT_POINT ]]; then
    mkdir $MNT_POINT;
    chmod -R 0777 $MNT_POINT;
fi;

# Mount the bucket
riofs -c ~/.config/riofs/riofs.conf.xml -o rw,allow_other,umask=2777,uid=1000,gid=1000 --cache-dir=/tmp/cache $S3_BUCKET $MNT_POINT;

mkdir $MNT_POINT/home;
mkdir $MNT_POINT/mysqlbak;

# Copy all "User" directories, except those owned by root
for filename in /home/* ; do
    # Get the owner of $filename.
    ACCT=$(stat -c '%U' "$filename");
    # If the file is a directory NOT owned by root, run backup.
    if [ -d "$filename" -a "$ACCT" != "root" ]; then
        # Rsync to the mount
        rsync -a /home/$filename $MNT_POINT/home;
    fi;
done;

# Copy all mysql backups
for mysqlbak in /mysqlbak/* ; do
    # Rsync to the mount
    rsync -a /mysqlbak/$mysqlbak $MNT_POINT/mysqlbak;
done;

# No need to keep it mounted
umount $MNT_POINT;
```

as you can see I am attempting to keep a backup of /mysqlbackup folder's contents, and the /home's contents (minus anything attached to the root account)

The issue is, when I run this script on my server I am getting the following errors:

```
rsync: change_dir "/home//home" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transfered (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

and

```
rsync: change_dir "/mysqlbak//mysqlbak" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transfered (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1039) [sender=3.0.6]
```

I can assure you that /home and /mysqlbak both exist.

How can I fix this so it properly syncs up to this mount?

/home and /mysqlbak are not created in the bucket

Comment: *luke, luke, learn to believe your error messages, luke*  ;-) `/home//home != /home/` . Good luck.

Comment: i think i can even go a step further... and completely get rid of the loops, and utilize the --exclude flag... ;-)   testing that part out now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
rsync -a /home/$filename $MNT_POINT/home;
```

by

```
rsync -a $filename $MNT_POINT/home;
```

and replace

```
rsync -a /mysqlbak/$mysqlbak $MNT_POINT/mysqlbak;
```

by

```
rsync -a $mysqlbak $MNT_POINT/mysqlbak;
```